# Differences between: 过来, 起来, 下来

Tags: difference, direction-complement

I encountered this multiple choice question:

> 这件事情说__________简单，做__________难

Where among the choices there are: 过来，起来，下来。

I always thought that their meaning was the same, but in this case the right answer is 起来.

So what's the difference between them? What do they actually emphasize in this specific case and in more general sentences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

过来 means "come over/ come here", 坐过来 means "sit over here"

下来 means "come down/ get down here) 坐下来 means "sit down"

起来 if used by itself, means "get up/ stand up", also carries a sense of "direction." when used in a combo like 
说起来 (when being talked about) 做起来 (when being worked on) it carries a meaning of "being brought up" or "being initiated." In this case, its usage is not necessarily indicative of "direction."

all three can be used by themselves or in a combo like the examples i give.

Comment: see previous question:What is the function of the complement 下来 in 买下来?

Comment: ［起来］１。趋向意义：与＂起＂相同，表示通过动作，人或物体由低处向高处移动。例如：气球升起来了。把头抬起来。大风刮起来一阵砂石，打在汽车的玻璃上。与＂上＂的区别‌​也与＂起＂相同。２。结果意义（一）：表示连接、结合以至固定。例如：他们勾结起来欺骗他不是第一次了。这两笔钱加起来一共是多少？你把头发盘起来，会凉快一点。快藏起来！‌​你怎么精神老也集中不起来？大家把他围起来了。他这么一说，我想起来了，我们十年以前见过。大楼盖起来了，很快就可以搬进去住了。３。结果意义（二）：表示＂突出＂、＂隆起‌​＂。例如：你看你，哭得眼睛都肿起来了。不小心，头上碰起一个包来。把胸挺起来！４。状态意义：表示进入一个新的状态。用在动词后时，表示动作开始进行－由静态进入动态；用‌​在形容词后，表示新的状态开始。例如：天阴了，下起雪来了。看见地上有一条蛇，他吓得叫了起来。听他说完，大家都笑了起来你不是不喜欢打球吗？怎么今天打起篮球来了？他这次‌​考试考得好一点，又得意起来了。他平时很节俭，今天怎么大方起来了？看见别人都为她高兴，小王心里觉得不是滋味起来。周围的同学这么关心爱护他，他逐渐活泼开朗起来。＂起来‌​＂与＂下来＂的不同：＂起来＂可以结合的形容词很广，＂下来＂可以结合的形容词很窄；此外，＂起来＂一般用在＂高、快、亮＂一类所谓正向形容词后，＂下来＂用在＂低、慢、暗‌​＂等所谓负向形容词后。但是当说话人觉得

Comment: 出现的变化不合常规时，＂起来＂也可以与负向形容词结合。例如：我抽了马一鞭子，马跑得反而慢起来了。大白天，怎么天忽然暗起来了？［下来］１。趋向意义（一）：表示人或‌​物体通过动作，由高处向低处移动，立足点在低处。例如：A：你快下来，有人找你。（A－在楼下）B：好，我就下去。（B－在楼上）我看见乘客们从飞机上下来了。（我－在地上‌​，不在飞机上）我从楼上搬下来几把椅子。（我－在楼下）２。趋向意义（二）：表示通过动作，人或物体退离立足点，移动的人或物体不在立足点上。例如：我向司令汇报完军情，退‌​下来一步，转身走出司令部。教练看他太累了，把他换下场来。（＂教练＂不在＂场上＂）３。结果意义（一）：表示分离至固定，着眼于主体分离的次要物体或物体的一部分。例如：‌​我很喜欢墙上那幅画，你摘下来给我吧。（着眼于分离物体＂画＂）我想记一个电话号码，你从本子上撕下一张纸来给我好吗？（着眼于＂一张纸＂）我用力从地理拔下来一个萝卜。这‌​个月剩下来的钱给你买双鞋吧。你别走了，留下来跟我们一起工作吧。请你把黑板上的句子抄下来。这件事我既然答应下来了，就一定会努力办好。开会的事定下来了。４。结果意义（‌​二）：表示＂凹陷＂，与＂下＂的结果意义（二）相同。例如：几天不吃饭，他就瘦下来了。车带瘪下来了，该打气了。５。结果意义（三）：表示完成一件费时、费力、需要克服一定‌​困难的动作行为。例如：一天的重体力

Comment: 力劳动干下来，身体好象散了一样，一步也不想走了。三年中文学下来，他的进步是明显的。上下文清楚时，＂下来＂前的动词可以不说，结果＂下来＂就直接用在时间词语后了。例如：一年下来，他完全习惯了。６。‌​状态意义：表示由动态转入静态，比＂下＂更常用。例如：汽车开道我门口，停了下来。你应该定下心来好好念书。大厅忽然静了下来，原来贵宾到了。天渐渐黑下来了。火车慢下来了‌​，原来要进站了。可以和＂下来＂结合的一般是＂暗＂、＂静＂、＂低＂一类的负向形容词。

Answer (score 2):

> 1. 这件事情说__________简单，做__________难

The answer should be 起来， 说起来容易，做起来难。
起来： is some kind of start doing something.  The original meaning of 起来, is "stand up", the first character "起" = stand up.

过来，起来，下来。
the "过" =  come
"下" = down

So, when you have done something, you may say, 这事情做下来还挺花时间的。
So "起" is a sort of opposite to "下".

Comment: Very interesting! Just to make sure I got it right, does 说起来容易，做起来难 mean the following: The matter easily comes up in a discussion, but it's hard to start doing something about it. Does the 做起來 really carry the meaning of "start doing" or merely doing? Would this be the right phrase for something politicians discuss, but nobody starts tackling?

Comment: cf. 3rd comment above: 状态补语（complement of state／manner) ４。（状态意义：表示进入一个新的状态))[expresses entering a new state]。用在动词后时，表示动作开始进行－由静态‌​进入动态；用‌​在形容词后，表示新的状态开始。例如：天阴了，下起雪来了... study example sentences in various dictionaries （starting with iciba，linguee）iciba:8. He shrugged whimsically, his eyes crinkling behind his glasses.他滑稽地耸了耸肩，眼镜片后面的双眼眯了起来。来自柯林斯例句9. Sue screamed, not loudly, more in surprise than terror.休尖叫起来，声音不大，吃惊多于恐惧。showing that entering a new state/condition, beginning of an action／activity in English may be sufficiently clear from context

Answer (score 0):

这件事情说起来简单（esay to say),做起来难(It's hard to do）。 第一个起来代表说的过程，第二个起来代表做的过程。The process of doing。             过来，起来，下来 ，一搬用做动词。但是在这道题里不是作为动词使用，很抱歉这个网站识别不了中文输入发的enter，我无法换行